# Select de dados vazios

Tags: java, swing, select, join, jtable

Meu código retorna todos os usuários, verificando se os mesmos pagaram o último mês, porém eu ligo duas tabelas, uma de todos os clientes com a tabela de pagamentos registrados, quero que imprima na `jTable` mesmo que não tenha registros de pagamento, porém o `left join` parece estar fazendo o mesmo papel de `inner join`,
segue o pedaço do código:

```
public void preencherTabela(){
    ArrayList dados = new ArrayList();
    String [] Colunas = new String[]{"CPF", "NOME", "DATA", "PAGO"};

    try{
        Connection con = Conexao.getConexao();
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet RS = stmt.executeQuery("Select cadastrarpac.nome, cadastrarpac.cpf, max(pagamento.data) from cadastrarpac "
                + "left join pagamento on (cadastrarpac.IdPac=pagamento.id_pac)");
        while(RS.next()){
            String nome = RS.getString("nome");
            String cpf = RS.getString("Cpf");
            String data = RS.getString("max(pagamento.data)");
            Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(data);  
            int data2 = date.getMonth()+1;
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            Date now = new Date();
            int data3 = now.getMonth()+1;


            boolean pago;   
            if (data2==data3){
                pago=true;
            if (data.isEmpty()){
                pago=false;
            }
            }else{
                pago=false;
            }

            dados.add(new Object[]{cpf, nome, data, pago});
        }
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
    ModeloTabela modelo = new ModeloTabela(dados, Colunas);
    table.setModel(modelo);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(80);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setResizable(false);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(176);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setResizable(false);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(75);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setResizable(false);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(80);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setResizable(false);
    table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
    table.setAutoResizeMode(table.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
    table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
}

Tabela pagamento:
id_pag int not null primary key, //id do registro de pagamento
id_pac int not null              //id do paciente(cliente)
data varchar(80) not null        //data do pagamento

insert into pagamento (id_pac, data) values (1, 20/04/2016)
insert into pagamento (id_pac, data) values (2, 21/04/2016)

Tabela cadastrarpac:
IdPac int not null primary key, //id do paciente 
Cpf varchar(12) not null,       //cpf 
Nome varchar(80) not null       //nome

insert into cadastrarpac (Cpf, Nome) values (088.758.960-0, Matheus) //id 1
insert into cadastrarpac (Cpf, Nome) values (089.858.966-0, Miriam)  //id 2
```

Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda,
Obrigado

Comment: Experiemente retirar o max de max(pagamento.data) e realize a consulta novamente.

Comment: Se fizer isso não sai nenhum resultado, nem os que tem registro de pagamento

Comment: Muito estranho, sua tabela da esquerda é a cadastrarpac, então deveria retornar algo se não tiver na pagamento. Faça outro teste retire os parenteses e deixe assim: pagamento.id_pac = cadastrarpac.IdPa

Comment: Continuou dando o mesmo resultado, muito estranho mesmo, pois estou utilizando o left e não o inner... era para trazer resultados não relacionados...

Comment: Edita a pergunta e posta a estrutura das duas tabelas com apenas 2 ou 3 campos para eu testar aqui.

Comment: Como exatamente você quer? o código das tabelas ou somente do que elas são formadas?

Comment: Queria o codigo e os dados que formam ela. Mas o codigo pode ser bem resumido e as informações também.

Comment: Pronto, assim ja serve?

Comment: Esse max() ta ferrando tudo ....

Comment: Não rola LEFT JOIN com agregação. Tenta obter esse máximo com uma subquery. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26928246/how-to-user-aggregate-function-with-left-join-mysql

Comment: Ou talvez um UNION como uma consulta que busque os clientes sem pagamento.

Comment: Testei aqui, o problema está no MAX, com ele a query só retorna 1 resultado, pois o outro não tem registro algum, então o MAX retorna null, já no outro registro, possui um valor, então ele é retornado. Retire o MAX e você conseguirá

Comment: Sem o max, retornou 2 resultados.

Comment: É que eu preciso do max para obter a ultima data registrada por cada usuário, como eu poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Faça um cadastro sem associar no pagamento, sem o max vai continuar trazendo somente os que tem pagamento....

Comment: Bom, ele retorna valor nulo certo? é isso mesmo que eu quero, mas eu queria que ele retornasse mostrando esse nulo, nao tem como?

Comment: Você vai ter que usar uma SUB query para fazer isso. Não dá para retornar o nulo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando se dá um `SELECT max()`, o retorno será sempre de no máximo um **registro/linha**.
Para que mais linhas apareçam, você tem que usar um `GROUP BY`, ou então não usar o `max()`.

Comment: Po, mt obrigado, resolveu parte do problema, tinha esquecido do group by, agora vou fazer alguns testes para conseguir o resultado esperado, valeu

Answer (score 0):

Problema resolvido, como a `jTable` não imprime o que é nulo, eu fiz com que cada vez que eu cadastrasse um novo paciente ele automaticamente tivesse seu primeiro pagamento com uma data "nula", no caso "01/01/0001" talvez não seja a maneira mais profissional, porém funcionou muito bem, obrigado a todos que se dispuseram a ajudar ;)